# AWS Multiple Elastic IPs to one instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip

I need some guide to lead me to setup multiple (6) ips for 6 websites (1 ip - 1 website) on one instance. or what to look for

I have found this http://www.ec2instances.info/
If it is true I need t2 small or better and somehow make it work with ips through VPC

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to attach additional ENIs to your instance.  On each of these ENIs you then associate a new EIP.

Docs:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html